# Page template not pulling data from database

Tags: php, wordpress, pdo

I have made a custom page template that will display release dates of when I finish making short movies. I have a page created using it and it loads fines. But I have put in a PDO database in the template to pull data. The only problem is that its not displaying anything and there is data in table.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=wordpress','****','*****');
            $sql = "SELECT * from release";
            $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute();

/*
Template Name: Test
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">
            <p align="center">
<?php while($row = $q->fetch()) { ?>
            <div id="name">
            <?php echo $row['name']; echo "hello"; ?>
            </div>
            <div id="site">
            <?php echo $row['site']; ?>
            </div>
            <div id="date">
            <?php echo $row['date']; ?>
            </div>      

 } ?>           
            </p>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
    <?php



} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error from Dedicated Database!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

 get_sidebar();
 get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What error do you get? Have you checked your error logs? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: @JohnConde I am not getting errors, just a white page. I have tried putting the file outside the wordpress install and still getting a white page with no error log.

Comment: If you got a blank page, make sure the error reporting option of PHP is turn into E_ALL to display all error and warning.

Comment: white page of death = error reporting and\or display off

Comment: Still nothing. I put error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of the page and still nothing happening. There is about 100 rows of data but its still not pulling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add <?php
```

before the last `} ?>` inside of content-section, like this:

```
            </div>      
<?php
 } ?>           
            </p>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```